# HTML+CSS A4 page with automatic page breaks

Tags: html, css, css-paged-media

I would like to print a HTML+CSS document to A4 paper.

My simplified code is here:

```
<html>
<head>
<style id="style_A4" media="print">
    @page {
        size:    A4 portrait;
    }
    body {
        width:   210mm;
        height:  297mm;
        padding: 20mm;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 0</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 1</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 2</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 3</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 4</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 5</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 6</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 7</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 8</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 9</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 10</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 11</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 12</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 13</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 14</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 15</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 16</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 17</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 18</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 19</p>
<p>The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox while colorless green ideas sleep furiously. - paragraph 20</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is the following: The bottom padding is missing from all pages, and the top padding is missing from the second page, as you can see on this image:

[image: Problem with padding]

I've found many solutions that apply manual page breaks with `page-break-after: always` or `page-break-before: always`. However, I would like if the pagination was automatic and all paddings were enforced on all pages, like in Microsoft Word. It is sufficient if it works on Chrome 95.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you might want to use page margins instead of the padding on `body`.
Make sure to set the page margins to the default value in the print dialog. If you don't, your custom page margins (as specified in CSS) will be overridden and don't have an effect.

Your stylesheet would look something like this:

```css
@page {
  size:    A4 portrait;
  margin: 20mm;
}

body {
  width:   210mm;
  height:  297mm;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, both as written in the answer and after substituting margin with padding, and unfortunately none of them works: there is no margin anywhere on any page.

Comment: Just to confirm: You set `margin` in the `@page` context (as above), right? I just tested it again and it does work for me.

Comment: Exactly. I even tried copy-pasting it directly from here. Maybe you see it working because you've set margins in the browser.

Comment: Just got your point: So you would like to see page margins while disabling them in the print dialog?

Comment: Could you elaborate why you'd like to keep that setting disabled? The page-context margin will be disabled/overridden if you set the option to anything but "Default".

Comment: OK, I thought the Default means that Chrome will use its own default (in non-standard units), not the one written in the HTML document.

Answer (score -1):

The below rules can help you add page break for tables.

```
table { 
    page-break-inside:auto 
}
tr    { 
    page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto 
}
```

Or try adding a div as:

```
<div class="page-break"></div>
```

with styles:

```
@media all {
    .page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is the manual method I mentioned in the question, and I would like to have automatic pagination.